# Фильтровать select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть два select элемента первый это марка авто, второе это модель авто.

Как можно фильтроват модель авто сравнивая с массивом `car_models` ?

При выборе Mercedes нужно показать только (Class C, Class A)

```js
var car_models = [
{'BMW':"X5"},
{'BMW':"X6"},
{'Mercedes':"Class C"},
{'Mercedes':"Class A"},
           ];


var $select1 = $( 'select[name=alsp-field-input-91]' ),
    $select2 = $( 'select[name=alsp-field-input-92]' ),
    $options = $select2.find( 'option' );

$select1.on( 'change', function() {
    var marka =  $(this).html();
  $select2.html( $options.filter(function () { return marka == "BMW"; }).val());
} ).trigger( 'change' );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="select_marka">
<option>BMW</option>
<option>Mercedes</option>
</select>

<select name="select_model">
<option>X5</option>
<option>X6</option>
<option>Class C</option>
<option>Class A</option>
<option>Class S</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Использую select2 скрипт вот тут оно не катит не как

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, зачем вам такой подход, ну попробую привести код)

```js
var car_models = [
{'BMW':"X5"},
{'BMW':"X6"},
{'Mercedes':"Class C"},
{'Mercedes':"Class A"},
           ];


var $select1 = $( 'select[name=select_marka]' ),
    $select2 = $( 'select[name=select_model]' ),
    $options = $select2.find( 'option' );

$select1.on( 'change', function() {
    var marka =  $(this).find(":selected").text();
    var model =  car_models.map(function(x){ if (x[marka]!='undefined') return x[marka]});
    
  
  $select2.html( $options.map(function () { 
   if (model.indexOf($(this).text())!=-1){
      return this;
   }
  
  }));

} ).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="select_marka">
<option>BMW</option>
<option>Mercedes</option>
</select>

<select name="select_model">
<option>X5</option>
<option>X6</option>
<option>Class C</option>
<option>Class A</option>
<option>Class S</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Долго объяснять)) Спасибо огромное.

Comment: к примеру мерседеса x5 не бывает как и  бмв class